# Java - Recursion with String returning with 0

Tags: java

I want to return the string "electric" with the number the user inputs.
I have created the program. The problem is that it's returning with 0 rather than showing the output only.
I know what the problem is, I just don't know the right solution.

Example :

> Input : 3

Output :

> Electric
>   Electric
>   Electric
>   0 <- should not have zero here.

```
import java.io.*;

public class quitx{
    public static BufferedReader v = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static int s;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Enter an integer  : ");
        s = Integer.parseInt(v.readLine());

            System.out.println(x(s));



    }

    public static int x(int s){
        if(s <= 0)
            return s;
        else{
            System.out.println("Electric!");
            return x (s - 1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What should the output be instead?? Your if statement returns the number if said number is <= 0 so logically, all it would put out is 0 or a number smaller than zero

Comment: Electric
Electric
Electric
without the zero, when I use this code, it has 0 under it.

Comment: Why not get rid of the if statement and make that method a void?

Answer (score 2):

The `x()` method returns an `int`. You don't want this `int` to be printed. Yet you're calling

```
System.out.println(x(s));
```

If you don't want the result to be printed, then... don't print it:

```
x(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method would always return 0, so instead of printing x(s), just call x(s) and then print s (not sure if you actually wanted to print that at the end)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the return type of the method:

```
public static void x(int s){
    if (s > 0) {
        System.out.println("Electric!");
        x(s - 1);
    }
}
```

And change the call to

```
x(s);
```